# Managing a service based on ACTION_SCREEN_OFF & ACTION_SCREEN_ON Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I'd like to stop/start my Android service based on the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF & ACTION_SCREEN_ON intents.

ACTION_SCREEN_OFF - stop my service to conserve battery life.
ACTION_SCREEN_ON  - start the service back up

I understand that I cannot register for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF & ACTION_SCREEN_ON in the Manifest and have successfully created a Broadcast Receiver in my service to capture the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF & ACTION_SCREEN_ON.

But, since I cannot register for the intents in the manifest, when I stop my service on ACTION_SCREEN_OFF...how can I possibly start it back up when the screen comes back on ?

Answer (score 1):

Your could create an Application subclass and register the receiver in onCreate,
but when your service is stopped, your application could be cleared from memory by android.
So you have to keep a long running service in background that listens for ACTION_SCREEN_ON/OFF intents